# symfony huge file download

Tags: php, file, symfony, download

I have controller in Symfony2, which provides file download.

```
/**
 * @Route("/polynomy/download/{polynomialId}", name="download_polynomial")
 */
public function polynomialDownloadAction( $polynomialId ) {
    $em = $this->get('doctrine')->getManager();
    $polynomial = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Polynomial')->findById($polynomialId);
    $filename = $polynomial->getFileLocation();

    $response = new Response();
    $response->headers->set('Cache-Control', 'private');
    $response->headers->set('Content-type', mime_content_type($filename));
    $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="'.basename($filename).'";');
    $response->headers->set('Content-length', filesize($filename));
    $response->sendHeaders();

    $response->setContent(readfile($filename));

    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('users_polynomials'));
}
```

This work just fine for small files (<100MB). But if I want to download file greater than 100MB I get an error (ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE).
I found, that problem is probably in php function `readfile()`, which causes memory exhaustion.

Is there a way in Symfony 2.6.1 how to download huge files without memory exhaustion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure. You want to use `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\BinaryFileResponse`.

```
$response = new BinaryFileResponse($filename);
```

That will also take care of headers for you automatically (though of course you can add more headers if needed).

Comment: I'm fighting with it today. I'm trying to send ~300mb file and getting File Not Found in browser. It works well with smaller files. Any solution?

Comment: Use StreamedResponse for large files rather. https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation.html#streaming-a-response